# Environment for config

Tags: bazel, bazelrc

`bazel build --config cxx20 --config opts ...`

I want to default to `--config cxx20 --config opts`. However I cannot change .bazelrc because other users use different configs. Is there a environment variable for config like `BAZEL_CXXOPTS`?

`export BAZEL_???="--config cxx20 --config opts"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution for this is to create a `.bazelrc.user` file and add a line `try-import %workspace%/.bazelrc.user` to your `.bazelrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your own configuration in `$HOME/.bazelrc`

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using an alias in your shell, like

```
alias bb='bazel build --config cxx20 --config opts'
```